How to access drop-down relationships in Laravel

Models :

USER

boards() : HasMany


BOARD

lists() : HasMany


LIST

tasks() : HasMany


TASK



Tables :
Board :

id
user_id

List :

id
board_id

Task :

id
list_id


How do I want to search for a task with an ID, but without creating a relationship in USER?
I can create a relationship in USER called tasks(), but I do not want to do this in this way. I want, for example:
$user = User::find(10);
$task = $user->boards()->lists()->tasks()->find($id);

Note that the tasks and lists table do not have a user_id field, only the board table
I TRY : $task = $user->boards()->lists()->tasks()->find($id);

Go the other way, start with what you want to get.
$userId = 10;
$tast = Task::query()
    ->whereHas('list', function($list) use ($userId) {
        $list->whereHas('board', function($board) use ($userId) {
            $board->where('user_id', $userId);
        });
    })
    ->find($id);

Short Form as suggested by @TBAWG:
$userId = 10;
$tast = Task::query()
    ->whereHas('list.board', function($board) use ($userId) {
        $board->where('user_id', $userId);
    })
    ->find($id);

You, of course, need the reverse relations of what you shared in your question.

Task -> list
list -> board

I would also suggest using findOrFail($id) instead of find($id) so it return a 404 in case of incorrect id.

what query()?? What's the point? I deleted it and it worked?

@none the static method query() is gonna be called anyway through __callstatic() that is how a query builder is initiated in all cases. But the difference is that when you add query(), your IDE will be able to identifie it and the rest of the methods.

I am not completely sure, but I guess Task::whereHas('list.board', function($board) use ($userId) { $board->where('user_id', $userId); })->firstOrFail($id); might work as well.

@TBAWG it does work in this case (not always), added it to the answer as shorter form.
